# Accurate pitch measurement with microcontrollers

Tags: python, audio, fft, frequency-analysis, autocorrelation

My goal is to measure the pitch of my violin with a small computer/microcontroller very accurately (a Raspberry Pi would be too big). I'm aiming for an accuracy of 0.1 Hz; 0.5 Hz could also work. The problem is that a violin produces a lot of frequencies known as harmonics. I only need the main frequency of each string, for example, 440 Hz.

I did a lot of research on the internet and performed some tests, but my measurements fluctuate by several Hz. I tried FFT and Autocorrelation in C++ on an older ESP32 with a "only" 20 kHz sampling rate.

My question is: What algorithm would work best in my case? Is an FFT capable of measuring as accurately as I need with such limited hardware power? What hardware is the best? Would a Raspberry Pico with MicroPython be a better option?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Using FFTs for this is most probably overkill. See if you can find cheaper alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pitch_detection_algorithm

Comment: Note musical instruments do not produce pure tones.  Most tuners accept plus or minus 10 cents as being "in-tune".  At 440Hz that corresponds to 437Hz to 443Hz.  So, your fluctuation may not be a measurement problem, but the actual fluctuations of your violin's note.

Comment: `0.1Hz` accuracy requires 5K$+ lab equipment, not a cheap MCU. Also what do you mean by `I only need the main frequency of each string, for example, 440 Hz`? do you just want to measure the amplitude of purely 440Hz?

Comment: remember that pitch related to frequency is on a logarithmic scale. Detecting to 0.5 Hz accuracy is not actually a helpful bench mark. 0.5 Hz to 1 Hz is HUGE in pitch terms. 1000.5Hz to 1001Hz is way beyond human hearing. I would first start with an Auto-Correlation algorithm, but you will need to "tidy up" the results. Electronics tuners can be a little clever to make them simple as typically you set what pitch you are aiming for. I would also recommend checking out the http://music.stackexchange.com for some theoretical insight

Comment: Fourier transforms that give enough temporal accuracy will be slow but also miss out more transient information. Plus, FFT are on a linear frequency scale so you will get a lot resolution where you do not need it.

Comment: dsprelated.com is also a good source. Here's one guy that's written different articles about [comples and real tones](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1490.php)